# Change Tracking w/o an Application to Sync with

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I work as part of a two man DBA team running SQL Server 2008 R2 with me being somewhat of an accidental DBA. We recently had an issue where a small table we hardly ever use ended up getting truncated. Both of us swear we didn't do it, but it happened nonetheless.

To avoid the situation in the future, we're interested in implementing change tracking. It's not really necessary for us to preserve the data that was changed so we decided against using change data capture.

With that said, the things I'm reading about change tracking seem to be more about using it to synchronize data with an application rather than simply recording all the changes. Can I use change tracking to simply keep a list of all the changes made in the last 6 months or something? Once I enable it for each database in the SQL Server GUI, where is the info stored? Any other info you may have on implementing this correctly would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for change tracking:

> The values of the primary key column is only information from the
>   tracked table that is recorded with the change information. These
>   values identify the rows that have been changed. To obtain the latest
>   data for those rows, an application can use the primary key column
>   values to join the source table with the tracked table.

So, if you're going to try to use this as a mechanism to somehow recover accidental deletions, I think you'll find it lacking. But don't take my word for it. Set up the following test:

1. In a test environment, set up a dummy table and enable change tracking on it.
2. Insert some data into the dummy table.
3. Delete the data
4. Recover the data using change tracking.

Despite having already dismissed CDC as an option, it sounds more in line with what you're after. CDC does keep track of non-primary key columns so if someone does a data modification accidentally, CDC will keep track of all of the values in the row(s) affected. It has the added benefit of not allowing table truncation because of how it's implemented (it uses the replication log reader).

Additionally, you can configure the CDC cleanup job to automatically purge data after any any amount of time you want (it sounds like 6 months is your retention period, which is completely doable).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will be running some tests later today or tomorrow. However, one thing I wanted to clear up is that we aren't actually looking to recover data. In the event that a truncation or insert, etc is done, we just want that event recorded. Based on what happened, we'll be able to simply reload the data using our ssis packages. Another reason I'm shying away from CDC is because it sounds like by keeping the data for even a short period of time it will increase our storage usage significantly. We currently load >100GB per week and don't want to double our usage.

Comment: Ah. If all you want to do is track whether someone deleted/otherwise changed data, take a look at SQL Audit. AFAIK, you can't look for truncations, but it will deal with standard deletes just fine. And you get the statement that ran along with who ran it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx